# Angular 4 with Django - Development Environment

Tags: javascript, python, django, angular, csrf

I am building an Angular4 application using Django rest_framework as a backend. I like having the browser automatically refresh to display my changes when working on my angular application. So I spin up both the Django server via `python manage.py runserver` and the angular dev server by running `npm start`. I have setup my `environment/environment.prod.ts` and `environment/environment.dev.ts` files to point to the proper API source as necessary.

After sorting out CORS I am running into a CSRF token issue. I have configured Django to use angular's default CSRF cookie/response header names of XSRF-TOKEN/X-XSRF-TOKEN respectively. All this is working just fine.

[Where the issue lies is that Angular does not automatically read the X-XSRF cookie or return the header.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18859) Ok, that's fine, I can write an interceptor to do that for me. And that would be OK - except that I cannot access the response headers in the interceptor...

```
import {DOCUMENT, ɵparseCookieValue as parseCookieValue} from '@angular/common';
import {Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpInterceptor, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor } from '@angular/common/http';

/**
 * `HttpInterceptor` which adds an XSRF token to eligible outgoing requests.
 */
@Injectable()

export class DevHttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
      private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const lcUrl = req.url.toLowerCase();
    console.log('intercepting');
    console.log(lcUrl);


    console.log(req.headers);

    // ***** HERE IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS *******/
    // if request is "GET" or "HEAD" retrieve the X-SRF token from the cookie
    // supplied by the server
    if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD') {
      return next.handle(req).map( (event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
          // here I want to read the "Set-Cookie" header and extract XSRF-TOKEN for later use
          console.log('--Response--');
          console.log(event);
          console.log(event.headers); // headers is empty
          // un-commenting the next line throws an error 
          // "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"
          // even stranger is that 'event' two lines back is now
          // an empty object if this line is uncommented???
          // console.log(event.headers.get('Set-Cookie'));
          return event;
      });
    }
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken();

    // Be careful not to overwrite an existing header of the same name.
    if (token !== null && !req.headers.has('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
      req = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token)});
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Why can't I view the response headers here? I can see them just fine in the chrome development console.

[image: Chrome Debug Console]

Comment: I have no idea about the topic at all, but keep in mind that the order of interceptors is important. The headers you are looking for are probably added later on in a different interceptor.

Comment: The headers are sent from the server - meaning this information should be available at all points in the application after the response has been received - which it has been if the code in question is being executed.